# Need assistance: constraint and result (Pyomo)

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to solve a dispatch problem for a power plant. However, I am not able to get the solution for certain scenarios. Your suggestions will be helpful.

Overview

I am trying to solve a generation planning problem for a power plant with two generators. I am using cplex solver with warm start (I am giving initial values of power and unit commitment) to solve the problem.
I also have a constraint that limits operating hours over the planning period. It is defined as below.

```
def OHLimit(model,i):
return  (0,sum(m.oh[t,i]for t in T),MCOH[i])
m.c1 = Constraint([0,1],rule = OHLimit)

Where,
i = Machine index [0,1]
t = Time interval
T = Planning period
m.oh[t,i] = Variable that represents operating hour in time ‘t’ for machine ‘i'
MCOH[i] = maximum allowable operating hours for machine ‘i’ for planning period ‘T’.
```

Scenario-1:

I am solving the problem for one week (168 hours)
MCOH = [1000,1000] therefore the constraint c1 will never bind.
Problem was able to solve with warm start. Operating hours for machines are as below.
GT01 = 100 OH
GT02 = 68 OH
Clearly, GT01 is utilized more.

Scenario-2:

I want to utilize both machines in equal manner. So, I changed MCOH = [90,1000]. I was expecting OH for GT01 to be reduced due to the constraint I have. However, I faced below challenges.

## 1. Problem could not warm start.

## 2. Problem is unable to solve after considerable amount of time.

I wonder if my way of formulating the constraint is not efficient or issue is somewhere else.

Your suggestions will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I can help for your whole problem, but for the warm-start, do you use cplex_persistent as the solver?